# Best Class Diagram generator (not eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, plugins, tool-uml

I am looking for a stand alone class diagram generator that takes the root folder as input and generates the class diagram. Share some of the best tools you might have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic Draw is pretty good: https://www.magicdraw.com/. You can use it as an Eclipse plug-in or as a stand-alone program. It can do round-tripping (class files to UML and UML to class files).

Answer (score 1):

you can try using BOUML; it is open source and although its developer announced in September 2010 that he ceased to develop BOUML, it seems to me that he still does bug
fixing.

Comment: It also permits to generate and synchronize source code from Java, PHP and others. A Good tool

Comment: This does not appear to be open source: http://www.bouml.fr/pricing.html
Or maybe I am misunderstanding? "The modeler of BOUML (bouml versus bouml.exe) need a valid license file to run (see legal mentions)."

Comment: it appears there had been some problems between the author of the software and some wikipedia people, after which the author said he will not support the software anymore; some time after, the software ceased to be free. There is a free version (4.22) at http://bouml.softpedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my MsC I discovered StarUML. It was a very efficient open source tool however, its developing seems stopped.

It accepts UML 2.0 completely. You must try it.

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I have used [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) once, it requires GraphViz. It includes a doclet so you can include the generated UML diagrams in your Javadoc. It hasn't been updated in a while, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ArgoUML, but it has some problems with generating relations between classes.
Perhaps, it's open-source and comfortable for non-large projects.